# How to use generic VecDeque?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Basically I need to make a structure that contains a `VecDeque` of `State`s. My code so far:

```
type State = [[bool]];
pub struct MyStruct {
    queue: VecDeque<State>,
}
impl MyStruct {...}
```

When compiling this code I end with

```
error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `[[bool]]` [E0277]
note: `[[bool]]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
```

I suppose that having `State` in the queue isn't good idea at all, so I tried a queue of references (which also fits into my application).

```
type State = [[bool]];
pub struct MyStruct {
    queue: VecDeque<&State>,
}
impl MyStruct {...}
```

In this case, even more weird error occures:

```
error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
```

How to create such a structure in order to work the way I wrote above? I'm really not a Rust expert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is that `[[bool]]` *makes no sense*.  `[bool]` is [dynamically sized](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsized-types.html), and you can't have an array of dynamically sized values, so `[[bool]]` is just impossible.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  The most obvious solution would be to just use `Vec` instead:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    queue: VecDeque<Vec<Vec<bool>>>,
}
```

As for your "even more weird error", that suggests to me that you haven't read the [Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), specifically the [chapter on Lifetimes](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html).  In order to write a structure containing borrowed pointers, you *have* to specify lifetimes.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I intended to make a fix-sized 2D array of bools. I need max. access speed hence I tried regular array as C/C++ uses. Is `Vec`fast?

Comment: If you want a fixed-sized array, use a fixed size array (like `[bool; 32]`).  `Vec` is just a dynamically sized, contiguous array, just like `std::vector` in C++.  Something like `[bool]` in Rust has *no* equivalent in C/C++; it's not representable in those languages at all.  Raw arrays like `bool []` don't *have* an exact equivalent in Rust, because they're fundamentally unsafe.  The closest would be borrowed arrays like `&[bool]`.  But really, just use `Vec` unless profiling shows it as a problem.

Comment: If you're worried about speed, you shouldn't be using double indirection. [Try flattening it.](http://is.gd/SC0eNa) If using fixed-length stack arrays this won't matter, though.